# C# Right to Left in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, rss, hebrew

I try to do TextBox moving, for Rss updates, but the problem is that the Rss text is also in Hebrew in English and also numbers, so every time it reaches the number it starts to go crazy :)

> Exmaple Rss = " * ynet - מבזקים * Ynet * ביקור טראמפ: הנשיא האמריקני
>   המריא מסעודיה לישראל * 15 שנות מאסר לבן ברדה שהרג אדם בקטטה בבת ים
>   לפני כארבע שנים * תאילנד: 24 פצועים בפיצוץ בבית חולים בבנגקוק * עשרות
>   אסירים ביטחוניים ששובתי רעב ופונו לבתי חולים החוזרו לכלא * בשל ביקור
>   טראמפ: יתוגברו הרכבות לירושלים וממנה * צפון קוריאה: מסוגלים להתחיל
>   בייצור המוני של טיל בליסטי שיכול להגיע ליפן * דיווח לבנוני: טראמפ
>   וא-סיסי סיכמו על פסגת שלום אזורית בשבועות הקרובים * דו\"ח: יותר ממאה
>   אלף עובדי ציבור פוטרו בטורקיה מאז ניסיון ההפיכה * התחזית: חם ויבש
>   מהרגיל לעונה * הפתעה ב-NBA: בוסטון ניצחה בקליבלנד, צמצמה ל-2:1 בסדרה"

```
public void Run_Ynet_Rss()
{
    Ynet_Rss.Text = "";
    foreach (string s in (Rss)
    {
        Ynet_Rss.Text = Ynet_Rss.Text + " * " + s;
    }
    Ynet_Rss.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
}
public void Update_Ynet_Rss()
{
    if (Ynet_Rss.Text == "")
    {
        Run_Ynet_Rss();
    }
    Ynet_Rss.Text = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(1);
    Ynet_Rss.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
}
```

Of course there is an DispatcherTimer that triggers the Update_Ynet_Rss function every few moments

Comment: Just an unfounded opinion: try RichTextBox.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the encoding.  The Hebrew is unicode (two bytes) while the numbers are ASCII (one byte).  Character/strings are two byte objects with a private property in the class to indicate if the character is one or two bytes.  The RSS function is not handling the encoding correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of thinking, I found the problem .. and here's the solution:

```
        public void Update_Ynet_Rss()
    {
        if(Ynet_Rss.Text == "")
        {
            Run_Ynet_Rss();
        }
        // Ynet_Rss.Text = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(0, Ynet_Rss.Text.Length-1);
        string s = Ynet_Rss.Text;
       // MessageBox.Show("Index = " + s.IndexOf("מבזקים"));
        if (s[0] >= 'א' && s[0] <= 'ת')
        {
            string tmp = "";
            string tmp2 = "";
            //Ynet_Rss.Text = Cutting(Ynet_Rss.Text, 0, s.IndexOf(" "));
            int EndIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
                {
                    EndIndex = i;
                    //MessageBox.Show("EndIndex = " + EndIndex + "s[i] = " + s[i].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(EndIndex == -1)
            {
             //   MessageBox.Show("EndIndex = " + EndIndex);
                EndIndex = s.Length;
            }
            //tmp = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(Ynet_Rss.Text.IndexOf(" "));
            tmp = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(EndIndex);
            tmp2 = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(0, EndIndex);
          //  MessageBox.Show("V1 = " + tmp2);
            tmp2 = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(0, tmp2.Length-1);
       //     MessageBox.Show("V2 = " + tmp2);
            Ynet_Rss.Text = tmp2 + tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            Ynet_Rss.Text = Ynet_Rss.Text.Substring(1);
        }

           Ynet_Rss.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
    }
```